# Xamarin Forms Prism: Is INavigationService necessary to be passed in constructor? Any other way apart from constructor injection

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

For prism framework in xamarin forms, to navigate from one view to another, is it mandatory to implement constructor inject and pass `INavigationService` in ViewModel's constructor?

I Can perform Navigation when I pass `INavigationService` as

```
public SomeViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
  _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SomeOtherPage");
}
```

But when I try to resolve whenever its needed, it doesn't work

```
public SomeViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
      ContainerProvider.Resolve<T>();// ContainerProvider is IContainerProvider
    }
```

Is there any other way to access `INavigationService` apart from constructor injection in every Viewmodel

Comment: Are you facing any error while using NavigationService with constructor injection? Also, you don't have to resolve NavigationService manually, it will be resolved via constructor injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re describing is an anti pattern, and generally just poor design. It also will not work because the Navigation Service is a very special service. It is created especially for each ViewModel as the Navigation Service must have the context of the Page you are navigating from. Without it, it would only work for resetting the Navigation Stack. To attempt to resolve the Navigation Service any other way in the ViewModel would likely break the MVVM design pattern.

If you want to use the Navigation Service you must inject it via the constructor. You may also simply use XAML Navigation in Prism 7.1. You can see a sample with the [Prism Tests](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.DI.Forms.Tests/Mocks/Views/XamlViewMockA.xaml). You can also see this in practice in this [demo app](https://github.com/dansiegel/SoCalCodeCamp.DeepDive).

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xaml="clr-namespace:Prism.Navigation.Xaml;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Class="Prism.DI.Forms.Tests.Mocks.Views.XamlViewMockA">
    <Button x:Name="testButton" Command="{xaml:NavigateTo 'XamlViewMockB'}">
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <xaml:NavigationParameters>
                <xaml:NavigationParameter Key="Foo" Value="Bar"/>
            </xaml:NavigationParameters>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Dan, thank you for the explanation, that helps a lot. I used to resolvers when needed instead of constructor injextion in MvvmCross, so thought there could be something similar. can you share example/Syntax of Xaml navigation?

Comment: I've added some samples of XAML based Navigation. Note that this doesn't make sense 100% of the time, for certain use cases it can work great. Also be sure to read the docs for a complete understanding of how to use it, there is actually quite a bit of functionality built in, including with determining when you can or cannot navigate.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I checked your example.